# Подробная проверка SMART параметров жесткого диска через PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Пытаюсь нагуглить возможность и существующие скрипты на PowerShell для проверки SMART параметров жесткого диска. Есть достаточно старые посты в которых есть скрипты, но (как мне кажется) эти скрипты выводят маленькое количество SMART параметров. Может кто то из Вас знает, как получать эти параметры и подскажет работающий скрипт?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вижу два варианта.

1. Надергать необходимых параметров. из
   `Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select *`
2. Требует сторонней софтины бесплатной smartmontools. И делать вызовы из powershell(она поддерживает консольные команды). Она позволить собрать все smart параметры hdd,ssd,nvme,raid итд. Если использовать этот вариант то готовых скриптов в интернете можно найти. В галереи PS есть даже готовый модуль для работы с ней. Wrapper-smartctl